# Looking for a blackboard bold (\mathbb) math font that is thicker than Latin Modern or Computer Modern

Tags: fonts

I am trying to find a blackboard bold math font that satisfies the following two conditions:

1. It looks similar to Latin Modern or Computer Modern, but **thicker**.
2. The space between the main character and its superscript of this font is as **small** as (or **smaller** to) the one of Latin Modern or Computer Modern.

The reason behind this is that I'm using the STIX Two font in XeLaTeX that requires the `unicode-math` package:

```
% STIX Two font
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{STIX2Text}[
  Extension       = .otf,
  UprightFont     = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont      = *-Italic,
  BoldFont        = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont  = *-BoldItalic ]

\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}
```

And the blackboard bold symbols of this package are just ugly to my taste. I can use Latin Modern's ones instead:

```
\let\mathbb\relax
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
```

but the symbols look too thin compared to the rest.

An alternative is using TeX Gyre fonts, e.g.:

```
\setmathfont[range={\mathbb}]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
```

but then I found that the space between the main character and its superscript is very large, which is also ugly.

Here's a comparison:

[image]

Could anybody suggest me with a font that satisfy the above two conditions?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a perfect one:

```
\setmathfont[range={\mathbb}]{Cambria Math}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like TeX Gyre Termes Math and don't expect to need a large number of different superscripts, you could just add a kern to move the superscript, like one of the arrangements below.

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

   \setmainfont[]{STIX Two Text}
   \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
   \setmathfont[range=bb]{Tex Gyre Termes Math}

   \usepackage{xparse}
   \DeclareDocumentCommand{\RN}{m O{-0.08}}{\mathbb{R}^{\kern#2em #1}}

   \newcommand*{\Rn}[1]{\mathbb{R}^{\kern-0.08em #1}}

   \begin{document}

   $\Rn{n_i}$

   $\RN{n_i}$

   $\mathbb{R}^{\kern-0.08em n_i}$

   $\RN{n_i}[0.0]$

   \end{document}
```

[image]