# \mathbb with stix

Tags: fonts, stix

Good morning,
I have a trouble with stix package: when I write `$\mathbb{R}$` I get a bad font.
How could I do to get the same font in amsmath using stix?
I alredy found a solution for my problem in this site: [Looking for a blackboard bold (\mathbb) math font that is thicker than Latin Modern or Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429156/looking-for-a-blackboard-bold-mathbb-math-font-that-is-thicker-than-latin-mod)... but it did not help me.
I hope in your help.
Thank you so much

Comment: the whole point of the stix package is to provide the stix font collection rather than the AMS fonts. Can you provide a test document and say what output you want? Define "bad" do you get an error or do you just mean that you don't like the stix font design?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Simply I dislike it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to load `\usepackage[bb=ams]{mathalpha}`, [or your blackboard font of choice,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) after `stix2`.  You might also want the `bbscaled=` option if the alphabet you load is too big or small.

Keep in mind that legacy TeX is limited to sixteen 8-bit math symbol fonts with 256 symbols each.  When you try to load more symbols on top of a big package like `stix2`, it is possible to run out..

If you can switch to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you could instead use the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`, This, for example, gives you the TeX Gyre Termes Math `\mathbb` instead of `\stix2`.

```
\usepackage{unicode-math} % Replaces all legacy font packages.

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[
   range=bb,
   Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

You can instead use `\usepackage{stix}` in PDFLaTeX or `\setmathfont{XITS Math}` in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to get version 1 of the STIX fonts.  The methods of replacing the blackboard alphabet are the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I use stix, not stix2. However you have solved my problem with  '\usepackage[bb=ams]{mathalpha}'

Comment: @Puck Thanks for the correction. I updated.