# Replacing stix2 fonts in combination with bm using pdflatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, bold, stix

This question arose from a comment on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/648538/195313), stating that `stix2` does not offer a bold `\mathcal`. Since I prefer the default `\mathcal` anyway, I would like to change the alphabet.

I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/601905/195313) using `mathalpha`. Unfortunately, in combination with `bm` this uses too many math fonts. I was thinking about switching to `unicode-math` since font selection is really easy there (and no font limitation). But (as far as I know) there is no unified boldening command like `bm` and one has to use `\symbf`, `\smybfcal` etc., i.e. it is not possible to do something like `\bm{ A \mathcal{A} \mathscr{A} }`. For this reason I would like to stick to `pdflatex`.

I am currently using the following MWE to fix the problem with too many math fonts

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newcommand\bmmax{0}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\ABC}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\ABC\\
\bm{\ABC}\\
\mathcal{\ABC}\\
\bm{\mathcal{\ABC}}\\
\mathscr{\ABC}\\
\bm{\mathscr{\ABC}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

besides the already mentioned warnings in the [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/648538/195313) this works. But I am not sure if this is the ideal way to do this.

### My Question:

What would be the "best" way of replacing the `stix2` font while using `bm`?

1. Use the `\newcommand\bmmax{0}` workaround, or is the
   `\newcommand\bmmax{0}` command problematic and should be avoided if
   possible?
2. Is there another way to replace one or more `sitx2` fonts without
   defining too many alphabets, maybe with a different way then
   `mathalfa`?
3. Can I edit a local copy of the `stix2.sty` file? (I already tried
   replacing the `stix2` alphabet in question with the one used by
   `stix`. Besides the fact that I do not really like the `stix`
   version of `\mathcal` either, I also replaced the integral symbols
   while doing so, which I would like to avoid.)
4. Should I perhaps purge the `bm` package at all and use `boldsymbol`
   instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648550/195313) to another question and [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648579/195313) from David Carlisle did the trick: If i use `LuaLaTex` or `XeLaTex` with

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}      {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet    {\mathcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\newcommand{\ABC}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\ABC\\
\bm{\ABC}\\
\mathcal{\ABC}\\
\bm{\mathcal{\ABC}}\\
\mathscr{\ABC}\\
\bm{\mathscr{\ABC}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

Alternatively i could use `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcmcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}` and `\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcmcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}` to declare a complete new alphabet and leave `stix2` unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented on your previous question, there is no point in using `bm` with `stix(2)`.

`bm` tries to add fonts from the bold math version into the normal math version, but stix has no additional fonts in the bold version, and already has more than the 16 available font slots, so there are no free slots for bm to use, and no fonts for it to add even if there were free slots.

Simply declare the computer modern fonts for calligraphic:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{stix2}
%\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
%\newcommand\bmmax{0}
%\usepackage{bm}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathcmcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathcmbfcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\newcommand{\ABC}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
1 \ABC\\
2 \mathbfit{\ABC}\\
3 \mathcal{\ABC}\\
4 \mathcmcal{\ABC}\\
5 \mathcmbfcal{\ABC}\\
6 \mathscr{\ABC}\\
7 \mathbfscr{\ABC}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Note that stix declares about 18 math fonts and this adds two more so way above the 16 allowed by TeX. If you have an old LaTeX release this is OK but you can not use more than 16 *in the document*. Since last year that has been relaxed and you can use all declared fonts so long as you do not use more than 16 in each *math expression*.

Comment: I am not quite sure if i actually need ``bm`` or if this is an overkill. But what i want is a _unified_ way to access boald versions of a variable. Background: I am writing a large document with many different variables, since i do not know if i have to change the name of some of those variables later one, i defined all with macros i.e. ``\newcommand{\myA}{A}``. If i would like tho change ``A`` to e.g ``B`` in the whole document i only need to change the command ``\myA``. Within the document i always use the normal font to denote a operator and bold mode to denote its matrix representation...

Comment: Since some of those variables are in basic math font and some in ``\mathcal`` i would like to have a unified way to access the bold version of each variable, keeping in mind that the variable could change during process and even switch to another font, i.e. i would like to keep the possibility to change ``\myA`` above to ``\newcommand{\myA}{\mathcal{A}}`` and still be to print the bold matrix representation of ``\myA`` without changing every ``\mathbf{\myA}`` to ``\mathbfcal{\myA}`` in the whole document. This is possible whit ``bm`` since ``\bm{A}`` and ``\bm{\mathcal{A}}`` both works.